# How to upsert a Hashmap into MongoDB Document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to structure a friendslist using MongoDB.

This is how I currently have it structured:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "601c570da04b75fabcd2705d"
    },
    "user_id": 1,
    "friendslist": {
         3 : true
     }
}
```

How can I create a query that does a put on my Hashmap (The hashmap is `"friendslist"`) and the key is 3 for the friend's id and the true flag is for the status of the pending friend request. (True meaing they are friends and false would be pending friend request)

This is what I currently have:

```
const upsertFriendId = db.collection('friends')
        .updateOne(
            { user_id: userId },
            { $set: { ???? : ????} },
            { upsert: true }
        );
```

I can't figure out the syntax that I need to put in the `$set` object.

Comment: What you would like to set the value to?

Comment: I want to update the hashmap "friendslist". If there is a user with the id 3 do nothing, else make a ```put``` on the hashmap to add a new user ```{ friend_id : true }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-order to ensure that you do not override the rest of the keys inside the `friendlist`, you can do an update like

```
const mongoFriendKey = `friendlist.${/* FRIEND_ID_VARIABLE_GOES_HERE */}`;

const upsertFriendId = db.collection('friends')
        .updateOne(
            {
               user_id: userId
            },
            {
               $set: 
                 {
                    [mongoFriendKey] : true
                 }
            },
            { upsert: true }
        );
```

In the above, replace the `/* FRIEND_ID_VARIABLE_GOES_HERE */` with the friend id variable. Doing that, the query will look for a friend with that specific Id, and then it will try to set it to `true` if not found, without overriding the entire `friendlist` object of yours.

Also, I hope you know what upsert does, if the update won't find the doc, then it will end up inserting one.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error: https://i.imgur.com/fsfBZYd.png does this also create a new map if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE it will add the id of the friend in the obj if it doesn't exist and will set it to true

Comment: My bad with the syntax error, give me a min please

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error when I use ` ` -- "Unexpected template string". When I switch to a single quotes instead 'friendlist.${friendId}' it gives me another error: The dollar ($) prefixed field '${friendId}' in 'friendlist.${friendId}' is not valid for storage.

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't think of doing it this way, I thought I would need a hashmap object, but I guess I don't

Comment: don't try to add the entire friendlist again else you might have to fetch first, append the key to the obj and then append the entire friendlist back which is not good. So better just use `key.[nestedkey] = value`. Cheers